# Let $2 = p_1 < p_2 < \dots$ be the increasing sequence of all prime numbers. For large $n$, which one is larger $2^{p_n}$ or $p_{2^n}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $2 = p_1 < p_2 < \dots$ be the increasing sequence of all prime numbers. For large $n$, which one is larger $2^{p_n}$ or $p_{2^n}$?

I need some help on this please.

I have tried using the Prime number theorem since $$\pi(x) \approx \frac{x}{\log x}$$

I used this expression for $x=2^{p_n}$ and $x=p_{2^n}$ but I couldn't make any progress.

$p_{2^n}$ is the $2^n$-th prime number.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: In addition to what @Shaun said, please use informative titles. And what is $p_{2^n}$ supposed to be? Please check that you wrote out everything correctly.

Comment: The $2^n$th prime, surely.  Y'all harshing on this thread so much haha  To the OP, this will probably help you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2773138/asymptotic-expression-for-the-nth-prime-number

Comment: For $n = 5, p_n = 11, 2^{(11)} = 2048,$ and $p_{2^5} = p_{(32)}$, which is nowhere near $2048.$ @JohnSamples I suspect, but can not easily prove, that you have it backwards.

Comment: @user2661923 Oh hahaha I didn't even realize the "dual meaning" of that part of my comment.  It was directed to "The Pointer" when he asks "what is $p_{2^n}$.  Very misleading, oops.  I still think this is the cleanest proof.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the prime number theorem, for sufficiently large $n$,  the $n$th prime is less than $n^2$.

Furthermore, all primes except $2$ or $3$ are $1 \text{ or } 5 \pmod 6$ (which means intuitively, that at most $1/3$ of numbers are prime). So $p_n > 3n -c$ for some constant $c$.

$$p_{2^n} < (2^n)^2 = 2^{2n}, \text{ while } 2^{p_n} > 2^{3n-c} = 2^{3n} / 2^c.$$

As $n \rightarrow \infty$, $2^{3n} / 2^c$ will be bigger than $2^{2n}$.  Therefore, for sufficiently large $n$, $2^{p_n}$ is bigger

Comment: Thank you very much. This was really helpful.

Comment: How do I justify the fact that almost all primes are 1 or 5 (mod 6)?

Comment: If it's 2 or 4 (mod 6) then it's even. If it's 3 (mod 6) , then it's divisible by 3.